# Fiddler on Windows 10: All Captured HTTPS Traffic Dies

Tags: https, fiddler

I've had a problem with Fiddler ever since my machine was upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  If I configure Fiddler to decrypt HTTPS traffic, any traffic it captures is, for lack of a better word, killed.

For example, if I visit the (HTTPS) page that documents configuring HTTPS decryption, without Fiddler, I see it as normal:

[image]

However, once I begin capturing traffic, and reload the page, I get this:

[image]

All of the responses feature this same exception message:

[image]

I only use Fiddler occasionally, when I need to see what's going into and out of my apps.  I could've sworn I was able to do this with HTTPS before migrating to Windows 10.  I'm not sure what changed, but Fiddler has become fairly useless to me now that all the traffic it captures fails.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Execute **Reset all Certificates** in Fiddler SSL options and then recreate and reinstall the Fiddler root certificate. When switching to Fiddler clear the browser cache to remove pinned certificates.

Comment: @Robert - Thanks, but unfortunately, even after doing those steps, and manually deleting all Fiddler DO_NOT_TRUST certs from my current user and the local machine (of which there were far more than I expected), and uninstalling/reinstalling FIddler, I still can't deal with HTTPS.  My colleagues can.  I suppose it's a gremlin somewhere in the depths of how this particular machine was set up.

Comment: After uninstallation make sure you also delete the registry settings: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Fiddler2`